# PHP static member variable returns empty value

Tags: php, backbone.js, static, laravel, member

First of all sorry for my bad english.

I'am using Laravel and Backbone.js to create a simple web app. On my server-side I have one method in which sql query is generated for fetching random data. I need to store that data so I'am using static member variable (array). But when I try to access that static variable from another method (the method named `ocijeni`) the value of array is empty.

(Server-side logic is accessed asynchronously with Backbone.js).

Here is my code:

```
class TestController extends BaseController {
    static private $odgovori = array();

    public function pitanja() {
        $pitanja = DB::select('select tocnoid,id,jedinstveno,pitanje,pomoc,odgovora,odgovorb,odgovorc from pitanja ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15');
        foreach ($pitanja as $pitanje => $value) {
            array_push(self::$odgovori, $value);
        }
    }

    public function ocijeni() {
        if (!Request::ajax()) {
            App::abort();
        } else {
            print_r(self::$odgovori);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug/dump your db-query output and see if there where any SQL errors.

Comment: there are no erros :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling your page from different AJAX calls then the value in the static variable will be reset.  Each call to the page will be at the same initial state.

If you want to retain the data across AJAX calls, you will want to look into sessions or storing the data into a cookie.

Comment: Thank you very much....that is exactly what is happening. Two different ajax calls...